# what is worng with that code? Only ($content = 'europe') is executing successfully... Remaining conditions are not executing

Tags: php

In that code only first condition is executing even if values are changed instead of `($content = 'europe')` to `($content = 'asia')` . Remaining conditions are not working.

```
function test(){

    if($content = 'europe'){
        $multi_tlds = $titan->getOption('wdc_europe');
    } elseif($content = 'asia'){
        $multi_tlds = $titan->getOption('wdc_asia');    
    } elseif($content = 'africa'){
        $multi_tlds = $titan->getOption('wdc_africa');  
    }

}
```

please check below code:

I have just mentioned my name like(pradeep). That is the exact place of code

```
<?php

    function wdc_display_func($content){
        check_ajax_referer( 'wdc_nonce', 'security' );
        $titan = TitanFramework::getInstance( 'wdc-options' );
        $whois = $titan->getOption( 'whois_option' );
        $integration = $titan->getOption( 'integration' );
        $extensions = $titan->getOption( 'extensions' );
        //$multi_tlds = $titan->getOption('wdc_multi_tlds');

    /*start - This is actual code (Pradeep)*/

        if($content == 'europe'){
            $multi_tlds = $titan->getOption('wdc_europe');
        } elseif($content == 'asia'){
            $multi_tlds = $titan->getOption('wdc_asia');    
        } elseif($content == 'africa'){
            $multi_tlds = $titan->getOption('wdc_africa');  
        }
        /* End - This is actual code (Pradeep)*/

        $ext_message = $titan->getOption( 'ext_message' );
        $additional_button_name = $titan->getOption( 'additional_button_name' );
        $additional_button_link = $titan->getOption( 'additional_button_link' );
        $custom_found_result_texts = $titan->getOption( 'custom_found_result_text' );
        if($custom_found_result_texts == '') $custom_found_result_texts = __('Congratulations! {domain} is available!', 'wdc');
        $custom_not_found_result_texts = $titan->getOption( 'custom_not_found_result_text' );
        if($custom_not_found_result_texts == '') $custom_not_found_result_texts = __('Sorry! {domain} is already taken!', 'wdc');
        if($ext_message == '') $ext_message = __('Sorry, we currently do not handle that particular tld.', 'wdc');

    if(isset($_POST['domain']))
    {
        if($integration == 'woocommerce' OR $integration == 'custom'){

            if($_POST['item_id'] != ''){
            $additional_button_link = $_POST['item_id'];
            }

        }
        $domain = str_replace(array('www.', 'http://'), NULL, $_POST['domain']);
        if (strpos($domain,'.') == false) {


   /*start - code (pradeep)*/
            if($multi_tlds == ''){
                $multi_tlds = array('com');
            }else{
                $multi_tlds = explode(',', $multi_tlds);
            }

        }else{
            list($sp, $split) = explode('.', $domain,2);
            $multi_tlds = array($split);
        }
    /*End - code (pradeep)*/

        if (function_exists('idn_to_ascii')) {
            $punny_domain = idn_to_ascii($domain);
        }else{
            $punny_domain = $domain;
            $punny_domain = preg_replace("/[^-a-zA-Z0-9.]+/", "", $punny_domain);
            $domain = $punny_domain;
        }
        $punny_domain = preg_replace("/[^-a-zA-Z0-9.]+/", "", $punny_domain);
        if(strlen($punny_domain) > 0)
        {

            include ('lib/DomainAvailability.php');  
            $Domains = new DomainAvailability();
            list($dom, $ext) = explode('.', $punny_domain, 2);


            foreach($multi_tlds as $ex)
            {
            $domain = $dom.'.'.$ex;
            if($extensions != ''){
            $tlds = explode(',', $extensions);
            if (!in_array($ex, $tlds)) {
                $result = array('status'=>2,
                                'domain'=>$domain, 
                                'text'=>    '<div class="callout callout-warning alert-warning clearfix">
                                            <div class="col-xs-10" style="padding-left:1px;text-align:left;">
                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" style="margin-right:1px;"></i> '.$ext_message.' 
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                            ');
                echo $result['text'];
                wp_die();
            }
            }

            $available = json_decode($Domains->is_available($domain));
            $custom_found_result_text = str_replace( '{domain}', $domain, $custom_found_result_texts );
            if($whois > 1) {
                    $whois_link = "<a href='".get_permalink($whois)."?&domain=$domain' target='_blank'><button id='whois' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right whois-btn'>WHOIS</button></a>";
                }else{
                    $whois_link = '';
                }

            if($integration == 'whmcs'){
    $check_ex = explode('.',$ex);

    if(count($check_ex) == 2){
        $ex_name = $check_ex[0]."_".$check_ex[1];
    }else{
        $ex_name = $check_ex[0];
    }
                $additional_button = "<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='submitform_$dom_$ex_name()'><button class='btn btn-success btn-xs pull-right order-btn'>$additional_button_name</button></a>";
            }elseif($integration == 'woocommerce'){
                //$additional_button = "<a href='?&add-to-cart=$additional_button_link&domain=$domain' target='_blank' class='btn btn-success btn-xs pull-right order-btn' >$additional_button_name</a>";
                $additional_button = "<a href='http://staging1.lowcostwebagency.com/domain-contact-form/' target='_blank' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right order-btn' >Ask for</a>";
                }elseif($integration == 'custom'){
                if(!$additional_button_name == '' AND !$additional_button_link == ''){
                    $additional_button_link = str_replace( '{domain}', $domain, $additional_button_link );
                    $additional_button = "<a class='btn btn-success btn-xs pull-right order-btn' href='$additional_button_link'>$additional_button_name</a>";
                }else{
                    $additional_button = '';
                }
            }else{
                $additional_button = '';
            }

            $custom_not_found_result_text = str_replace( '{domain}', $domain, $custom_not_found_result_texts );
            $whmcs = "<script type='text/javascript'>
                    function submitform_$dom_$ex_name()
                    {
                      document.whmcs_$dom_$ex_name.submit();
                    }
                    </script>
                    <form method='post' name='whmcs_$dom_$ex_name' id='whmcs' action='$additional_button_link/cart.php?a=add&domain=register'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='domains[]' value='$domain' >
                    <input type='hidden' name='domainsregperiod[$domain]' value='1'>
                    </form>";
            if ($available->status == 1) {
                    $result = array('status'=>1,
                                    'domain'=>$domain, 
                                    'text'=>    '<div class="callout callout-success alert-success clearfix available">
                                                <div class="col-xs-10" style="padding-left:1px;text-align:left;">
                                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" style="margin-right:1px;"></i> '.$custom_found_result_text.' 
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-2" style="padding-right:1px">'.$additional_button.' '.$whmcs.'</div>
                                                </div>
                                                ');
                    echo $result['text'];

            } elseif($available->status == 0) {
                    $result = array('status'=>0,
                                    'domain'=>$domain, 
                                    'text'=>    '<div class="callout callout-danger alert-danger clearfix not-available">
                                                <div class="col-xs-10" style="padding-left:1px;text-align:left;">
                                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="margin-right:1px;"></i> '.$custom_not_found_result_text.' 
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-2" style="padding-right:1px">'.$whois_link.'</div>
                                                </div>
                                                ');
                    echo $result['text'];
            }elseif ($available->status == 2) {
                    $result = array('status'=>2,
                                    'domain'=>$domain, 
                                    'text'=>    '<div class="callout callout-warning alert-warning clearfix notfound">
                                                <div class="col-xs-10" style="padding-left:1px;text-align:left;">
                                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" style="margin-right:1px;"></i> WHOIS server not found for that TLD 
                                                </div>
                                                </div>
                                                ');
                    echo $result['text'];

            }
        }
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Please enter the domain name';
        }
    }
    wp_die();
    }

    add_action('wp_ajax_wdc_display','wdc_display_func');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wdc_display','wdc_display_func');

    function wdc_display_dashboard(){
        echo do_shortcode('[wpdomainchecker]');
    }

    function wdc_add_dashboard_widgets() {

        wp_add_dashboard_widget(
                     'wdc_dashboard_widget',         
                     'WP Domain Checker',        
                     'wdc_display_dashboard'

            );  
    }
    add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'wdc_add_dashboard_widgets' );

    function wdc_whois_shortcode(){

        if(isset($_GET['domain'])){

            echo '<h3>Whois record for <b>'.htmlspecialchars($_GET['domain']).'</b></h3>';

            require("lib/whoisClass.php");
            $whois=new Whois;
            echo "<pre>";
            if (function_exists('idn_to_ascii')) {
            echo $whois->whoislookup(idn_to_ascii($_GET['domain']));
            }else{
            echo $whois->whoislookup($_GET['domain']);
            }
            echo "</pre>";
        }



    }
    add_shortcode( 'wpdomainwhois', 'wdc_whois_shortcode' );

    function wdc_display_shortcode($atts){

        $titan = TitanFramework::getInstance( 'wdc-options' );
        $item_id = $titan->getOption( 'additional_button_link' );
        $image = $titan->getOption( 'loading_image' );
        $recaptcha_enable = $titan->getOption( 'recaptcha' );
        $placeholder = $titan->getOption( 'input_placeholder' );
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image);
        if($image == '') {
            $image = plugins_url( '/images/load.gif', __FILE__ );
        }else{
            $image = $image[0];
        }
            $atts = shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'width' => '900',
                'button' => 'Check',
                'recaptcha' => 'no',
                'item_id' => $item_id,
                'tld' => ''
            ), $atts );
        if($atts['recaptcha'] == 'yes'){
            $show_recaptcha = "<p> <div id='wdc-recaptcha' class='wdc' ></div></p>";
        }else{
            $show_recaptcha = "";
        }
    $content = "<div id='domain-form'>
        <div id='wdc-style'>
            <form method='post' action='./' id='form' class='pure-form'> 
                <input type='hidden' name='item_id' value='{$atts['item_id']}'>
                <input type='hidden' name='tld' value='{$atts['tld']}'>
                <div class='input-group' style='max-width:{$atts["width"]}px;'>
                    <input type='text' class='form-control' autocomplete='off' id='Search' name='domain' placeholder='$placeholder'>
                        <span class='input-group-btn'>
                        <button type='submit' id='Submit' class='btn btn-default btn-info'>{$atts["button"]}</button>
                        </span>
                </div>
            {$show_recaptcha}
            <div id='loading'><img src='$image'></img></div>

 <!--start - code (pradeep) -->

    <div class='container'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-sm-3'>
    <fieldset>
    <input type='radio' name='asia' value='asia'> Asia<br>
    <input type='radio' name='europe' value='europe'> Europe<br>
    </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-3'>
    <fieldset>
      <input type='radio' name='africa' value='africa'> Africa<br>
    </fieldset>
    </div>
    </div></div>

    <!-- end - code (pradeep) -->

    </form>
    <div style='max-width:{$atts["width"]}px;'>
            <div id='results' title='API' class='result'></div>
    </div>
        </div>
    </div>";

    return $content;

    }
```

?>

**Remaing code (continue from above code)... If you want you can go through...I hope you may find solution:**

```
     <?php

    add_shortcode( 'wpdomainchecker', 'wdc_display_shortcode' );

    /* Woocommerce Function */
    function custom_add_to_cart_redirect() { 
        if($_REQUEST['domain']){
        return WC()->cart->get_cart_url(); 
        }
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'custom_add_to_cart_redirect' );

    function save_name_on_wdc_field( $cart_item_key, $product_id = null, $quantity= null, $variation_id= null, $variation= null ) {

        WC()->session->set( $cart_item_key.'_domain', $_GET['domain'] );
        WC()->session->set( $cart_item_key.'_price', $_GET['price'] );

    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'save_name_on_wdc_field', 1, 5 );

    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price');

    function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
        $titan = TitanFramework::getInstance( 'wdc-options' );

        global $woocommerce;
        $tld = array();
        $extensions = $titan->getOption( 'wdc_custom_price' );
        $extensions = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $extensions);
        $tlds = explode(',', $extensions);

        foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        if(WC()->session->get( $cart_item_key.'_domain')){
        $domain = WC()->session->get( $cart_item_key.'_domain');
        list($domain, $ext) = explode('.', $domain, 2);

         foreach ($tlds as $key => $value) {
            $tld = explode('|', $value);
            if($ext == $tld[0]){
                $price = $tld[1];
                $cart_item['data']->price = $price;
            }
        }
        }
        }
     }

    function render_meta_on_cart_item( $title = null, $cart_item = null, $cart_item_key = null ) {
        global $product_id;
        if( $cart_item_key && is_cart() ) {

            if(WC()->session->get( $cart_item_key.'_domain')){
            echo $title. '<dl class="">
                     <dt class="">Domain : </dt>
                     <dd class=""><p>'. WC()->session->get( $cart_item_key.'_domain') .'</p></dd>           
                  </dl>';
            }else{
                echo $title;
            }
        }else {
            echo $title;
        }
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'render_meta_on_cart_item', 1, 3 );

    function render_meta_on_checkout_order_review_item( $quantity = null, $cart_item = null, $cart_item_key = null ) {
        if( $cart_item_key ) {
            if(WC()->session->get( $cart_item_key.'_domain')){
            echo $quantity. '<dl class="">
                     <dt class="">Domain : </dt>
                     <dd class=""><p>'. WC()->session->get( $cart_item_key.'_domain') .'</p></dd>
                  </dl>';
            }else{
                echo $quantity;
            }
        }
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'render_meta_on_checkout_order_review_item', 1, 3 );

    function wdc_order_meta_handler( $item_id, $values, $cart_item_key ) {
        if(WC()->session->get( $cart_item_key.'_domain')){
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, "Domain", WC()->session->get( $cart_item_key.'_domain') );
        }   

    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'wdc_order_meta_handler', 1, 3 );

    function wdc_force_individual_cart_items($cart_item_data, $product_id)
    {
        $titan = TitanFramework::getInstance( 'wdc-options' );
        $id = $titan->getOption( 'additional_button_link' );
        $unique_cart_item_key = md5( microtime().rand() );
        $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = $unique_cart_item_key;

        return $cart_item_data;

    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data','wdc_force_individual_cart_items', 10, 2 );

    add_filter('woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link','wdc_replace_add_to_cart');
    function wdc_replace_add_to_cart() {
    global $product;
     $link = sprintf( '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="button product_type_%s">%s</a>',
            esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
            esc_attr( $product->id ),
            esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
            esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
            esc_attr( $product->product_type ),
            esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
        );
      $links = sprintf( '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="button product_type_%s">%s</a>',
            esc_url( get_permalink($product->id) ),
            esc_attr( $product->id ),
            esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
            esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
            esc_attr( $product->product_type ),
            esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
        );

       if(get_post_meta( $product->id, 'wdc_hide_addtocart', true ) == 'yes'){
        return $links;
       }else{
        return $link;
       }
    }

    function wdc_remove_cart_button(){
    $product_id = get_the_ID();
        if(get_post_meta( $product_id, 'wdc_hide_addtocart', true ) == 'yes'){
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
        }
    }
    add_action('wp','wdc_remove_cart_button');

    function wdc_woo_add_custom_general_fields() {

      global $woocommerce, $post;

      echo '<div class="options_group">';

        woocommerce_wp_checkbox( 
        array( 
        'id'            => 'wdc_hide_addtocart', 
        'wrapper_class' => 'wdc_item_edit_class', 
        'label'         => __('WDC?', 'wdc' ), 
        'description'   => __( 'Check me if you want to hide Add to Cart button on single product page.', 'wdc' ) 
        )
    );

      echo '</div>';

    }

    function wdc_woo_add_custom_general_fields_save( $post_id ){
        $woocommerce_checkbox = isset( $_POST['wdc_hide_addtocart'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'wdc_hide_addtocart', $woocommerce_checkbox );
    }

    // Display Fields
    add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'wdc_woo_add_custom_general_fields' );

    // Save Fields
    add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'wdc_woo_add_custom_general_fields_save' );
    /* Woocommerce End Function */


    function wdc_recaptcha_func() {
        check_ajax_referer( 'wdc_nonce', 'security' );

        if(isset($_POST['response']))
        {
            $titan = TitanFramework::getInstance( 'wdc-options' );
            $captcha = $_POST['response'];
            $secret_key = $titan->getOption( 'recaptcha_secretkey' );
            $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secret_key."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
            echo $response;

        }
    wp_die();
    }
    add_action('wp_ajax_wdc_recaptcha','wdc_recaptcha_func');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wdc_recaptcha','wdc_recaptcha_func');

    function wdc_recaptcha_dis_func() {
        check_ajax_referer( 'wdc_nonce', 'security' );

            echo json_encode(array('success' => 'true'));

    wp_die();
    }
    add_action('wp_ajax_wdc_recaptcha_dis','wdc_recaptcha_dis_func');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wdc_recaptcha_dis','wdc_recaptcha_dis_func');

    function wdc_options() {
        $titan = TitanFramework::getInstance( 'wdc-options' );
        global $panel;

        $panel = $titan->createAdminPanel( array(
        'name' => 'WP Domain Checker',
        'parent' => 'options-general.php',
        ) );

        $generaltab = $panel->createTab( array(
        'name' => 'General',
        ) );

        $generaltab->createOption( array(
        'name' => 'Custom Available Result Text',
        'id' => 'custom_found_result_text',
        'type' => 'textarea',
        'desc' => 'This is custom available result text. Use {domain} to replace domain name.'
        ) );

        $generaltab->createOption( array(
        'name' => 'Custom Not Available Result Text',
        'id' => 'custom_not_found_result_text',
        'type' => 'textarea',
        'desc' => 'This is custom not available result text. Use template tag {domain} to replace domain name.'
        ) );

        $generaltab->createOption( array(
        'name' => 'Input Placeholder',
        'id' => 'input_placeholder',
        'type' => 'text',
        'desc' => 'Placeholder for domain input.'
        ) );

        $generaltab->createOption( array(
        'name' => 'Loading Image',
        'id' => 'loading_image',
        'type' => 'upload',
        'desc' => 'Upload your image'
        ) );
        $pages=get_pages( array('post_type' => 'page','post_status' => 'publish') );
        foreach ($pages as $page) {
            $whois_page['disable'] = 'Disable';
            $whois_page[$page->ID] = $page->post_title;
        }
        $generaltab->createOption( array(
        'name' => 'Whois Page',
        'id' => 'whois_option',
        'type' => 'select',
        'options' => $whois_page,
        'desc' => 'Enable or disable whois link if domain not available',
        'default' => 'disable',
        ) );

        $generaltab->createOption( array(
        'name' => 'Integration With',
        'id' => 'integration',
        'type' => 'select',
        'options' => array(
            'disable' => 'Disable',
            'whmcs' => 'WHMCS',
            'woocommerce' => 'Woocommerce',
            'custom' => 'Custom Link',
        ),
        'desc' => 'Enable or disable integration.',
        'default' => 'disable',
        ) );

        $generaltab->createOption( array(
        'name' => 'Integration Button Text',
        'id' => 'additional_button_name',
        'type' => 'text',
        'desc' => 'Integration Button Text. (e.g.: "ORDER NOW")'
        ) );

        $generaltab->createOption( array(
        'name' => 'Integration Button Link',
        'id' => 'additional_button_link',
        'type' => 'text',
        'desc' => 'Integration button link. (e.g. for WHMCS: "http://billing.host.com"). <a href="http://asdqwe.net/wordpress-plugins/wp-domain-checker-docs/" target="_blank">Documentation</a><br>
                    For custom link, you can use template tag {domain} to include domain in the link. <br>e.g: http://godaddy.com/?aff=12345&domain={domain}'
        ) );

        $generaltab->createOption( array(
        'name' => 'Supported TLD Extensions',
        'id' => 'extensions',
        'type' => 'textarea',
        'desc' => 'Allow only specific extensions to check. separate by comma for each extension. (e.g: com,net,org,co.uk,co.id)<br>Leave it blank to allow all extensions.'
        ) );

        $generaltab->createOption( array(
        'name' => 'Not Supported TLD Extensions Messages',
        'id' => 'ext_message',
        'type' => 'text',
        'desc' => 'Not Supported TLD Extensions Messages. (e.g.: "Sorry, we currently do not handle that particular tld.")'
        ) );

        $generaltab->createOption( array(
        'name' => 'WooCommerce Custom Price',
        'id' => 'wdc_custom_price',
        'type' => 'textarea',
        'desc' => 'Allow custom price for specific tld. (e.g: com|9,net|10,org|11,co.uk|12,co.id|13)'
        ) );

        $generaltab->createOption( array(
        'name' => 'Multiple TLDs Check',
        'id' => 'wdc_multi_tlds',
        'type' => 'textarea',
        'desc' => 'Multiple TLDs check if user not define tld on the domain. (e.g: com,net,org,info)'
        ) );


 /*Start- code (Pradeep)*/

        $generaltab->createOption( array(
        'name' => 'Asia TLDs Check',
        'id' => 'wdc_asia',
        'type' => 'textarea',
        'desc' => 'Asia TLDs check if user not define tld on the domain. (e.g: in,ch,rocks,club)'
        ) );


        $generaltab->createOption( array(
        'name' => 'Europe TLDs Check',
        'id' => 'wdc_europe',
        'type' => 'textarea',
        'desc' => 'Europe TLDs check if user not define tld on the domain. (e.g: fr,it,pro)'
        ) );

        $generaltab->createOption( array(
        'name' => 'Africa TLDs Check',
        'id' => 'wdc_africa',
        'type' => 'textarea',
        'desc' => 'Africa TLDs check if user not define tld on the domain. (e.g: link,af,host,me)'
        ) );

         /*End- code (Pradeep)*/

        $recaptchaTab = $panel->createTab( array(
        'name' => 'reCaptcha',
        ) );




        $panel->createOption( array(
            'type' => 'save'
        ) );

    }
    add_action( 'tf_create_options', 'wdc_options' );



    class wdc_widget extends WP_Widget {
        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct(false, $name = __('WP Domain Checker Widget'));
        }
        function form($instance) {
                if (isset($instance['title'])) {
                    $title = $instance['title'];
                    $width = $instance['width'];
                    $button = $instance['button'];
                    $recaptcha = $instance['recaptcha'];
                }else{
                    $title = "Domain Availability Check";
                    $width = "";
                    $button = "";
                    $recaptcha = "no";
                }
        ?>

        <?php
        }

    }

    function register_wdc_widget()
    {
        register_widget( 'wdc_widget' );
    }
    add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_wdc_widget');


        ?>
```

Comment: I think this is what you need `==`. `=` will be treated as assignment, which is always true

Comment: You are assigning values, instead of comparing. Use `==`

Comment: @Abhi now not even a single condition is working

Answer (score 0):

this is declaring a variable

```
$content = 'europe'
```

should be ==

```
$content='asia';
function test(){

    if($content == 'europe'){
        $multi_tlds = $titan->getOption('wdc_europe');
    } elseif($content == 'asia'){
        $multi_tlds = $titan->getOption('wdc_asia');    
    } elseif($content == 'africa'){
        $multi_tlds = $titan->getOption('wdc_africa');  
    }

}

<input type='radio' name='asia' value='asia'> Asia<br>
    <input type='radio' name='europe' value='europe'> Europe<br>
    </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-3'>
    <fieldset>
      <input type='radio' name='africa' value='africa'> Africa<br>
```

this piece of code is wrong they should all have the same name

```
name='myregionchoice'
```

then you process it as post

```
$regionchoice=$_POST['item_id'];
```

then in the if statements

```
if($mygreionchoice == 'europe'){
        $multi_tlds = $titan->getOption('wdc_europe');
    } elseif($myregionchoice == 'asia'){
        $multi_tlds = $titan->getOption('wdc_asia');    
    } elseif($myregionchoice == 'africa'){
        $multi_tlds = $titan->getOption('wdc_africa');  
    }

}
```

to use a radio button choosing options  the name has to be the same for all
check the code below for the format of how to do this and where you should process data before and after the page reloads and check the function format and how i get the output from the function and how the if statement must look like you can test this code it works

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="anyname" action="" method="post">
            <input type="radio" name="choice" value="asia"/>asia
            <input type="radio" name="choice" value="africa"/>africa
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="my radio choice">
        </form>
<?php 


    function choose(){
        //declare it is a global variable from outside the function
        global $choice;


        if ($choice =='africa') {
        $test='you choose africa';
        }   
        elseif ($choice =='asia'){
        $test='you choose asia';
        }
        //returning the output of the function
        return $test;
        }



    //here you proccess the data after the page reloads

    if (!empty($_POST['choice'])){  
        $choice=$_POST["choice"];
        //running the function
        choose();
        //getting the output from the function
        $test=choose();
        echo 'this is the data after the page reloads :',$test;
        }



    //here you process the data before the page reloads
    if ((isset($_POST["submit"])) && ($_POST["submit"]!="")){
        $choice=$_POST["choice"];
        //running the function
        choose();
        //getting the output from the function
        $test=choose();

        }
?>


    <body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes i have already tired with that

Comment: before posting the question i have tired this but not working

Comment: then it might be a variable problem echo out all your variables

Comment: Im wondering if it was a variable problem, then how come first condition is executing successfully.

Comment: I mean only the  first position of condition is working perfectly.

Comment: try it with the variable i added and see if it goes to asia and where is this $content variable defined?

Comment: It was defined already. In that $content they are passing the form.

Comment: can you show me how i want to make sure that piece of code is right because the problem is not here

Comment: how do i send you full code?

Comment: you can just edit your question then add the piece with the variable

Comment: now you can  check

Comment: your problem is somewhere in that $content=div i will  have to check more to find what exactly

Comment: ok once you done... let you tell me...

Comment: found it check my edit but you need to define that post data somewhere

Comment: where should I post the data ?

Comment: can you define in my above code?

Comment: I have modified the code as you defined... but solution remains the same like executes first position ($myreionchoice == 'europe') of if condition....

Comment: I agree with your solution bro... but whereas in my code there is a multiple functions declared known... I mean form is defined in one function and if condition is defined in another function known...  but in your code only function declared... so I don't known how do I get solution... That is what I requested you to edit my code.

Answer (score 0):

`==` is for comparison and `=` equates the variable with the value. You need to compare inside if instead of equating.

Answer (score 0):

`$content = 'europe'` is an assignment sentence, which always returns true and therefore the code unther that condition is always executed.

I think what you are looking for is a comparison statement, that woul be `$content == 'europe'` (and the same of all the other values).

Also, you should then pass the `$content` variable to your function, otherwise is undefined:

```
function test($content) {...}
```

Comment: I have did what you have given here... but error remains the same

Comment: You need to define the `$content` variable, check my update

Comment: let me check and tell you